# Was "the right stuff" ever really the right stuff?

Tags: aviation-history

In the history of the culture of aviation, to what extent has the popular image of "the right stuff" required of a pilot **ever** matched the characteristics actually sought in aviation?

In this popular image, the pilot with "the right stuff" is imbued with, *amongst other characteristics*:

- fearlessness
- adventure
- masculinity
- a strong streak of individualism
- stubborn single-mindedness
- quick-thinking
- sexiness
- cool
- self-sufficiency
- a disregard for limits that bind lesser individuals
- a distaste for rules
- a stronger belief in himself than in authority
- a strong intuitive sense of how to deal with problems in the air
- ... and others corresponding to the picture of the pilot who gets to walk around with a swagger because he deserves it, as vividly described in Tom Wolfe's [The Right Stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Right_Stuff_(book)), but also represented that way through countless other descriptions and depictions in popular culture.

Comment: Hi Daniele, I like the question but it may be not a good fit here, it seems difficult to answer without introducing an opinion. Perhaps there is a way to edit the question and prevent answers driven by opinions.

Comment: I'm not qualified to judge sexy in male pilots, but people like Bob Hoover, Tex Anderson, and Chuck Yeager come to mind on the other qualities.

Comment: @mins For example, do military aviation training academies (or did they ever, which is my real question, since I doubt they seek them out now) seek out or encourage the swashbuckling adventurers, the so-called alpha males, highly-competitive top-gun achievers? Or have such characteristics *never* made for a good fit? Whatever the answer, those will be historical facts about aviation training culture and standards, not matters of opinion.

Comment: `swaggering mavericks are dangerous and successful` - I figured out what you meant the second time I read it, but the first time was a little strange

Comment: `cool, calm, unflappable under pressure, courageous, quick-thinking` is the right stuff, has always been and still is (a student pilot that panics easily is unlikely to pass and instructors often throw problems to students to see if they are unflappable under pressure and quick-thinking). On the other hand `swaggering` is not the right stuff - don't get me wrong, it is in popular imagination because we like to associate "cool", as in cool kids in high school, with cool professions like F1 driver and pilots when what makes them successful is their attention to detail to the point of geekiness

Comment: @SteveV. Amazing the difference a comma can make! Thanks.

Comment: Question's closed now, but one note: The great thing about the phrase "the right stuff" is that it's tautological. Whoever made the cut would have the right stuff, and those with the right stuff would make the cut. The list of attributes you mention is almost like cold reading, as _something_ will apply to one pilot or another. Hopefully unflappable and quick-thinking is pretty general, but swaggering and sexy? Don't know if someone like Neil Armstrong would've fit that in the classic sense, even though he did have enough right stuff to manually land the Eagle on the Moon with little fuel left

Comment: I've rewritten the question. It's asking exactly the same thing, but perhaps it's clearer that this is asking a question about the historical facts of the culture of aviation.

Answer (score 16):

Well, kind of,

The technical portrayal of test pilots in that film received negative reviews with real test pilots.  I know Chuck Yeager did not like his portrayal by Sam Shepherd and director Philip Kaufman, particularly with the NF-104 accident at the end of the film.  While the scene is based on a real accident which Yeager did have, it was part of a scheduled test flight with established test points and not Yeager throwing on a pressure suit and jumping into the cockpit for a joyride with a YOLO type attitude.

Flight test and test pilot work is rigorously planned out, methodically didacted and cogitated, with multiple contingency plans and contingency plans for those if they don’t work.  Long gone are the days where you strapped your little pink fanny into a crate, pushed it off a cliff, and hoped for the best on the way down.  Test pilots and flight test engineers are very bright and methodical people who are intimately familiar with the systems of the aircraft they are flight testing and have spent a great deal of time thinking about all the ways something can go wrong and what they intend to do if they encounter this problem.  Hundreds, if not thousands of hours have been spent in systems and and flight simulation scenarios, not only evaluating these hypotheses, but making detailed plans for their test points they want to evaluate during flight.  Finally the flight testing itself is a slow and methodical affair, slowly and carefully increasing the performance envelope with each flight and thoroughly evaluating and addressing anomalies once encountered before continuing.  As one test pilot once put it, “We try to make flight testing as boring as possible.”

As to being cool, calm, unflappable under pressure, quick thinking and courageous being the defining qualities of 'the right stuff' in a pilot.  I would argue that they ARE useful to a pilot anywhere.  Remember US Airways Flight 1549's Capt Chesley 'Sully' Sullenberger?  That guy was faced with one of the most challenging scenarios out there and was a cool as a refrigerated cucumber throughout.  You may not be exploring and mapping out the absolute edges of an F-35's flight envelope, but those skills can come in handy with any kind of emergency situation which you might face.

Remember there is a difference between these qualities and having hazardous attitudes e.g. anti-authority, machismo, etc.  As Yeager once put it "If you want to grow old as a pilot, you gotta know when to push it and when to back off."  In addition flight test is a considerably different animal than it was back in Yeager's day, thanks in part to Yeager and a few unfortunates who now have a street at Edwards named after them.

Test flying isn't about being taking big risks; its a gradual and methodical process of exploring the flight characteristics of an aircraft and having multiple contingency plans to make it as safe as possible.  In short, good Aeronautical Decision Making really IS 'The Right Stuff'.  Risk takers, the macho guys, or the just plain stupid get weeded out, either by their superiors or by Natural Selection.

Comment: As the saying goes, "There are old pilots, and there are bald pilots, but there are no bald bold pilots".

Comment: The spelling on that comment makes no sense.  I’m guessing you meant ‘There are old pilots and there are bold pilots, but there are no old, bold pilots’?

Comment: @CarloFelicione - It's way funnier the other way though

Comment: My dad was an old bald pilot.

Answer (score 3):

[Psychologists know](http://www.livescience.com/17116-life-extremes-leaders-followers.html) that some people are more leaders than others. Case in point: When the ferry [Estonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Estonia) sunk in 1994, some people went down to sit in their cars (because they felt safe there), others just waited for someone to rescue them and only maybe 10% went up to the lifeboats and actively tried to rescue themselves.

Guess which personality type would qualify as test pilots.

While Tom Wolfe exaggerates the typical test pilot into a macho type who is actually not ideally suited to the task, there is some truth in the observation that [some people perform far better in stressful and unanticipated situations](https://hbr.org/1998/07/how-hardwired-is-human-behavior) than others. The leader type likes to think for him/herself and stays level-headed when other types would panic and rely on leaders for direction.

Comment: I don't think "leadership" and "cool under stress" are really at all related.  In your example, "cool under stress" people would have tried to rescue themselves, "leaders" would have tried to get other people to do something.  If the leaders were also cool under stress, it might actually be the right thing, but we have lots of real-world examples of leaders reacting badly to stress, and mis-leading their followers.

Comment: @jamesqf: You interpret "leaders" wrongly. Focus on the others instead: They prefer to wait for others and follow orders. Would that make them better test pilots?

Comment: @Peter Kämpf: I don't think so.  There are really three kinds of personalities here: the leader, who convinces people to follow; the follower, who readily follows anyone acting like a leader; and the individualist, who goes ahead and does what seems sensible regarldess of other people.  From the little I know of what's involved in test-piloting, I doubt that either of the first two would make particularly good test pilots.

Comment: @jamesqf, they are totally related. You ain't going to save anybody if you are not "cool under stress". The ability to lead others is just a bonus on top of that, and one that under stress you _don't_ need, because _under stress_ those who panic will follow anybody who seems to know what they are doing.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: But my points are 1) you can be cool under stress without being a leader (and vice versa, of course); and 2) leadership does not seem to be a necessary (or even desirable) quality in a test pilot.